# Set Column Value based on Other Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-columns, dynamic-pivot

I have table generated via Pivot Table with the Dynamic Column Names. The result of the pivot is stored in a temp table ##MyTable.

Structure of ##MyTable with Sample Columns and data is as follows,

```
dFrom    dTo   0    1800.00    1801.00    2400.00    2401.00    20000.00  
00:15    00:30 NULL 2.1        NULL       NULL       NULL       0  
00:30    00:45 NULL 2.1        NULL       NULL       NULL       0  
.  
.  
.  
02:00    02:15 NULL NULL       NULL       3.5        NULL       0
```

*All these columns except dFrom, dTo, 0 and 20000.00 are dynamic.*
Now the requirement is to update the value of adjacent Column to the column that contains a value, other than NULL, to 0. For example, in the above case, in Column 1801.00 & 2401.00 (which are dynamic columns) the value is be set to 0 for rows with 00:15 - 00:30, 00:30 - 00:45 and 02:00 - 02:15 respectively.
Also, the column [0] must contain the same value as in any column that contain a value other than NULL. Like in above case, for rows with 00:15 - 00:30 & 00:30 - 00:45, the Column [0] should contain 2.1; and for row with 02:00 - 02:15, the Column [0] should contain 3.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **All these columns except dFrom, dTo, 0 and 20000.00 are dynamic.** how you are giving dynamic name to the columns.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I am sorry I didn't get it. (What DB are you talking about?). SQL Server based DB...

Comment: Could you show a statement in which dynamically define columns, please?

Answer (score 2):

For columns where you want to replace the NULL to 0, use the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

`ISNULL(dynamicColumn1, 0)`

For column [0] you can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function:

```
COALESCE(dynamicColumn1, dynamicColumn2, etc)
```

Dynamic statement

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeadersForSelect varchar(max),
        @PivotColumnHeadersForPivot varchar(max)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeadersForSelect = 
  COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeadersForSelect + CASE WHEN [mPriceKW] = 0.00 THEN '[0.00]' ELSE ',ISNULL([' 
  + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + '], 0.0) AS [' + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']' END, 
  + CASE WHEN [mPriceKW] = 0.00 THEN '[0.00]' ELSE 'ISNULL([' + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) 
  + '], 0.0) AS [' + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']' END),
       @PivotColumnHeadersForPivot =
  COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeadersForPivot + ',[' + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']', 
  + '[' + CAST([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']')      
FROM PivotColumn
GROUP BY [mPriceKW]
ORDER BY [mPriceKW] ASC

SET @PivotColumnHeadersForSelect = 
  REPLACE(@PivotColumnHeadersForSelect, '[0.00]', 'COALESCE(' + @PivotColumnHeadersForPivot + ') AS [0.00]')
--SELECT @PivotColumnHeadersForSelect, @PivotColumnHeadersForPivot

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @PivotTableSQL = N' 
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb.dbo.##MyTable'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.##MyTable
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.##MyTable
FROM (SELECT dFrom, dTo, ' + @PivotColumnHeadersForSelect + '
      FROM (
            SELECT a.dFrom, a.dTo ,a.[mPriceKW] , a.fQuantumMW 
            FROM PivotColumn a 
            WHERE a.iBid = 1 
             ) TableDate 
PIVOT (min(fQuantumMW) FOR [mPriceKW] IN (' + @PivotColumnHeadersForPivot + ') 
      ) PivotTable) dt ' 
--PRINT @PivotTableSQL      
EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)

SELECT *
FROM ##MyTable
```

Also see demo on [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7c4a/1)

Comment: Alexander Fedorenko: dynamicColumn name is not known; its dynamic.

Comment: @Dhruv Ganesh I realize that...It shows only the functions is necessary to your dynamically creating statements. Could you show a statement in which dynamically define columns, please?

Comment: DECLARE PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT PivotColumnHeaders =
 COALESCE(
  PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']', + '[' + cast([mPriceKW] as varchar(10)) + ']')
from <table> order by [mPriceKW] asc


DECLARE PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET PivotTableSQL = N'
select * into ##MyTable 
from (
 SELECT *
 FROM (
  Select a.dFrom, 
 a.dTo ,a.[mPriceKW] , a.fQuantumMW from <table> a 
where a.iBid = ' + <ID> + '
 ) TableDate
 PIVOT (
 min(fQuantumMW)
  FOR [mPriceKW] IN (
   ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
  )
 ) PivotTable) dt
'
EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)